# Geting list of protobuf message objects from the SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, protocol-buffers

I want to get a list of protobuf message objects from the Spring boot app.
I did manage to get a single protobuf message object from the app but getting a list of them throws exception.

```sh
...
2020-01-24 14:57:02.359 ERROR 15883 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN[0]->com.example.demo.Lecture["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["parserForType"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Parser and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN[0]->com.example.demo.Lecture["unknownFields"]->com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet["parserForType"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
...
```

My code (simplified).

#### tl;dr

- **create Spring boot app**
- **generate class from `proto` file**
- **try return `List` of generated class objects (RESTful)**

My code (simplified).
**Controler**

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("/timetable")
public class RestController {

    @PostMapping("/single")      // Works
    private Lecture getLecture(@RequestBody Lecture lecture) {
        log.info("Single2 got: {}", lecture);
        return Lecture.newBuilder(lecture)
                .setDuration(lecture.getDuration() +1)
                .build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")       // Does not work
    private @ResponseBody List<Lecture> getLectures() {
        return List.of(
                Lecture.newBuilder()
                        .setDuration(1)
                        .setWeekDay(Lecture.WeekDay.MONDAY)
                        .setModule(Module.newBuilder().setName("Math1").build())
                        .build()
                // ... 
        );
    }
}
```

**App**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<!-- ... -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--        https://dzone.com/articles/exposing-microservices-over-rest-protocol-buffers-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.protobuf-java-format</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-format</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<!-- ... -->
```

I generate message objects using:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SRC_DIR=../proto
DST_DIR=../../../target/
mkdir -p $DST_DIR
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/college.proto
```

**proto file**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package my.college;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.example.demo";

message Module {
    string name = 1;
    // ... other
}

message Lecture {
    WeekDay weekDay = 1;
    Module module = 2;
    uint32 duration = 3;
    // ... other

    enum WeekDay {
        SUNDAY = 0;
        MONDAY = 1;
        // ...
    }
}
```

I did found [simmilar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136430/problem-returning-stream-of-responses-from-grpc-service-to-restful-client?noredirect=1#comment105924485_58136430) but it had no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround**
I couldn't find a solution to the problem so came up with a workaround.
Instead of returning generated protobuf message objects I returned wrappers for those objects. Using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation it could be done:

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data // Lombok magic
public class Module {
    private String name;
    // ...

    public Module(ie.gmit.proto.Module moduleProto){
        this.name = moduleProto.getName();
        // ...
    }
}
```

This workaround doesn't feel very bad as it uses standard Spring boot dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

Spring will choose the `HttpMessageConverter` that matches the appropriate converter for the object type of your response body.  In this case, it is likely choosing `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` of the `ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` because your response body has type List.

`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` implements `HttpMessageConverter<Object>`
`ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` implements `HttpMessageConverter<Message>`

Since `ProtobufJsonFormatHttpMessageConverter` does not support serializing a List type, we can instead tell the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` how to serialize the Message type through configuration.

**Solution**

A bean of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` can be used to register a serializer for Message types.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return o -> o.serializerByType(Message.class, new JsonSerializer<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Message value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeRawValue(JsonFormat.printer().print(value));
        }
    });
}
```